# How to get the current system date format like dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy in client side

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam using the datepicker control in which, i have to set the date format like dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy format based on my browser date format.

Example : if my browser date is  22/06/2019 - I have to set as "dd/MM/yyyy" format in datepicker.
if my browser date is  02/16/2019 - I have to set as "mm/dd/yyyy" format in datepicker.

How can we achieve this scenario in typescript or angular 6

Comment: Please dont use both `angular` and `angularjs` tags

Comment: try new Date().toLocaleDateString()

Comment: I have tried the new Date().toLocaleDateString() -  it display the date as "3/27/2019".  I need the format of date whether it is dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy. so that i can set the format to my datepicker. Can you suggest other possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Angular Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) for that

```
{{yourDate | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}}

                or

{{yourDate | date: 'mm/dd/yyyy'}}
```

> https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe